# dataTables filter specific column without using footer

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, laravel-5

is there anyway to search the columns only second col without using filter?

i've tried using:

```
   "aoColumnDefs": [
    { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [ 1 ] }]
```

---

```
 "searchCols":[null, {"search":""}, null]
```

here is my complete script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  oTable = $("#roles").dataTable({
    "processing":"true",
    "serverSide": "true",
    "ajax": "roles",
    "columns":[
        {data: 'id', name:'id'},
        {data: 'name', name:'name'},
        {data:  'link', name:'link'}
        {data: 'actions', name:'actions'}
    ],
    "oClasses": {
        "sFilter": "pull-right",
        "sFilterInput": "form-control input-rounded ml-sm"

    },
    "Dom": "<'row'<'col-md-6 hidden-xs'l><'col-md-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-md-6'i><'col-md-6'p>>",
    "oLanguage": {
        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_",
        "sInfo": "Showing <strong>_START_ to _END_</strong> of _TOTAL_ entries"
    },
    "searchCols":[null, {"search":""}, null]
});
});
```

is there anyway so i can only filter name column without using footer filter?
because if i not specific a  column to be filter, when i tried to search it will get an error because there is actions column.